# No ARIMA model able to be estimated Error in R forecast package - auto.arima

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am using `auto.arima` from `forecast` package for multiple datasets in HPC server. The train data always has 24 data points with month-wise data for the past 2 years. The data also contains an external regressor. It has been working fine since long, but I encountered an error suddenly for one dataset alone.The error message says-

```
<simpleError in search.arima(x, d, D, max.p, max.q, max.P, max.Q, max.order,     stationary, ic, trace, approximation, xreg = xreg, offset = offset,     allowdrift = allowdrift, allowmean = allowmean, parallel = parallel,     num.cores = num.cores): No ARIMA model able to be estimated>
```

The code that I used is -

```
auto_arima <- ts(data$y, start=min(data$DATE), frequency=12)
auto_arima <- auto.arima(auto_arima, xreg = data$x1, stepwise=FALSE, approximation=FALSE, seasonal=TRUE)
```

The dataset that was producing the error is

```
structure(list(DATE = structure(c(17804, 17835, 17865, 17896, 
17927, 17955, 17986, 18016, 18047, 18077, 18108, 18139, 18169, 
18200, 18230, 18261, 18292, 18321, 18352, 18382, 18413, 18443, 
18474, 18505), class = "Date"), x1 = c(21, 22, 21, 22, 22, 19, 
22, 21, 22, 21, 22, 22, 21, 22, 21, 22, 22, 19, 22, 21, 22, 21, 
22, 22), y = c(17532306871, 41826190703, 7748403270, 14959015398, 
15241717931, 18655759009, 15393151016, 15251081090, 14516497716, 
13974303432, 11254893416, 17410813458, 14446411746, 12876827127, 
17609512917, 12179664532, 17473491954, 18447419416, 28262667160, 
36623989143, 28711285833, 28711285833, 28711285833, 28711285833
)), row.names = c(NA, 24L), class = "data.frame")
```

When I run this code in my windows machine with Rversion 4.0.2 installed, it is working fine (ARIMA model (0,1,0) is being built) but when running the same code with the same data in HPC server, I am facing the error described above. I am facing the same error even when I try to execute the same code with Rversion 3.6.1 installed from RStudio in another windows machine.

Is this because of R version difference or am I missing something? Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The R version probably makes no difference here. The package version is what matters more. Here you are using the forecast package, and the `auto.arima` algorithm has had a few improvements and bug fixes over the years. The current CRAN version of forecast is v8.12 and it returns the ARIMA(0,1,0) model.

Comment: Thanks Rob Hyndman. I understand this & shall update the pckg to latest version. I am curious to know if there is any technical reason, for this error when using older version of forecast pkg. Using the same data if I decrease the 22nd datapoint value by 1000, the older version also returns ARIMA(0,1,0) model. I don't understand the difference between the original data & updated one. I am confused why the former throws an error while the later returns a valid ARIMA model. I shall be grateful if you can throw some light on this or point me to any materials or documentations. Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't said what package versions you are using, so it is impossible to answer what changes might have led to these results. You can see the full history of the changes to the `auto.arima()` function at https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/commits/master/R/newarima2.R

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much. This really helps.